# Query for get the specific record

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hi i have a table in which records as follows,every item have some variants and their quantity. i want to fetch only those item's record in which at least 3 variants value exist. ( a items have some qty in 3 variants but b have quantity only 2 variants, so i need only those record who have values at least in 3 records)

```
a   80  2
a   85  3
a   90  4
b   85  2
b   90  1
c   80  34
c   85  45
c   90  56
c   95  67
d   80  5
d   85  3
d   90  124
d   95  23
d   100 98
e   95  4
f   80  3
f   85  232
f   90  2
f   95  3
f   100 34
```

Result should be:

```
a   80  2
a   85  3
a   90  4
c   80  34
c   85  45
c   90  56
c   95  67
d   80  5
d   85  3
d   90  124
d   95  23
d   100 98
f   80  3
f   85  232
f   90  2
f   95  3
f   100 34
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with `left join`/`is not null`:

```
select t1.* 
from tbl t1
left join ( select item 
            from tbl
            group by item
            having count(item) >= 3) t2 on t1.item = t2.item 
where t2.item is not null
```

or `in`:

```
select t1.* 
from tbl t1
where t1.item in  ( select item 
                    from tbl
                    group by item
                    having count(item) >= 3)
```

or `exists`:

```
select t1.* 
from tbl t1
where exist  ( select *
               from tbl
               where item = t1.item
               group by item
               having count(item) >= 3)
```

Comment: Hi...Thanks for the querry. i am getting an error (Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'select'. Severity 15
An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'Code'. Severity 15). data type of item is code in my table.

Comment: Hi...Thanks for the querry. i am getting an error (Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'select'. Severity 15 An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'Code'. Severity 15). data type of item is code in my table

Comment: @MukeshUniyal: There is no `Code` in my query.

Comment: ITEM field's data type is code in my table...may be the reason of error.

Comment: @MukeshUniyal: Update your answer with a query you are using.

Comment: select t1.* 
from [BCL_201516$Item Ledger Entry] t1
where t1.[Variant Code] in  ( select [Variant Code]
                    from [BCL_201516$Item Ledger Entry]
                    group by [Variant Code]
                    having count([Variant Code]) >= 3) and t1.[Location Code] in ('RED','BLUE','GREEN' )
not getting the required data with this query, i need only data in which at least 3 variants have sum qty..Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from a t1 where (select count(*) from a t2 where t2.x=t1.x)>2;
```

`a` is the table name, `x` is the first column's name.

Comment: I have single table..please let me know what is t1 & t2.

Comment: No luck with this query..i am still getting the record which have values in single variant...